# Best strategy for manual memory management using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a recommended strategy for dealing with external libraries which expect manually managed raw pointers. For example a method which takes a vector of pointers:

```
ALibraryFunc(std::vector<ALibraryData*> p);
```

so generally you'd create your vector with something like:

```
std::vector<ALibraryData*> myVec;
for(...)
{
    myVec.push_back(new ALibraryData(args));
}
//and then
ret = ALibraryFunc(myVec);
//and then
for(auto &a:myVec)
{
    delete a;
}
myVec.clear();
```

I'd much prefer to use smart pointers but the library will not take them. This leaves me wondering if something like this is more stinky than just doing it manually:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ALibraryData>> myVecUP;
std::vector<ALibraryData*> myVec;
for(...)
{
    myVecUP.push_back(std::make_unique<ALibraryData>(args));
    myVec.push_back(myVecUP.back().get());
}
//and then
ret = ALibraryFunc(myVec);
myVec.clear();
myVecUP.clear();
```

The second version seems safer in case of exceptions or mistakes but it does risk dangling pointers. Am i missing something obvious here? What do/would you do?

Comment: Note:  this solution is a little tricky to get exception safe, as an exception can get thrown by the myVec.push_back(...).  If you go this route, you would want to write it as try { myVec.push_back(myVecUP.back().get()); } catch (...) { myVecUP.pop_back(); throw; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'scope exit' idiom :

```
//open scope block
{
    std::vector<ALibraryData*> myVec;
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    struct MyVecRAIICleaner{ 
      std::vector<ALibraryData*> * myVecPtr;
      ~MyVecRAIICleaner(){ 
        if (myVecPtr) {
         for(auto& a: *myVecPtr)
            delete a;
         myVecPtr->clear();
        }
       }
    } myRAIICleaner = {&myVec};
    ////////////////////////////////////////
   for(...)
   {
       myVec.push_back(new ALibraryData(args));
    }
    //and then
    ret = ALibraryFunc(myVec);

    /** You needn't below code. */
    ////and then 
    //for(auto &a:myVec)
    //{
    //    delete a;
    //}
    //myVec.clear();

}// end scope block
```

EDIT:
I'm sorry, but Wojtek Surowka's answer is not exception safe or required extra try catch block in constructor.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a small class which will own the vector of raw pointers, and delete the pointers in the destructor:

```
struct VecOwner {
 std::vector<ALibraryData*> vec;
 VecOwner(<some arguments>)
 {
     // fill the vector here
 }
 ~VecOwner()  
 {
   for(auto &a:vec)
     delete a;
   vec.clear();
 }
};
```

you should be able to reuse the class in all places where you use the library.

Comment: This is probably the best way of doing it and my first example is just a simplification of this. I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: If you want to have a vector which somehow consists of smart pointers and can be also visible as vector of raw pointers - I do not think it is possible within valid C++.

Comment: Make sure to never copy `VecOwner`, or you'll get double deletes.

Comment: @ildjarn you can go further and make the copy constructor private so there's no chance of making that mistake.

Comment: @Mark : Indeed, I only meant to call attention to the issue. :-]